# OAuth Token Response to Angular View (cookie)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cookies, express, oauth

I've been struggling with this for a couple hours now and need some help.  I've created a simple app that presents the user with a "Login Using Google" button in an angular view that redirects the user to the Google Oauth page.  Here's the controller code that calls the login() function when the button is pressed:

```
angular.module('dashApp').controller('SigninCtrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.login=function() {
    var client_id="191641883719-5eu80vgnbci49dg3fk47grs85e0iaf9d.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    var scope="email";
    var redirect_uri="http://local.host:9000/api/auth/google";
    var response_type="code";
    var url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope="+scope+"&client_id="+client_id+"&redirect_uri="+redirect_uri+
    "&response_type="+response_type;
    window.location.replace(url);
  };
});
```

The redirect URI set in my google project redirects to a server page to this server page:

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash');
var request = require('request');
var qs = require('querystring');
var fs = require('fs');

// Get list of auths
exports.google_get = function (req,res){
  var code = req.query.code,
      error = req.query.error;

  if(code){
    //make https post request to google for auth token
    var token_request = qs.stringify({
      grant_type: "authorization_code",
      code: code,
      client_id: "191641883719-5eu80vgnbci49dg3fk47grs85e0iaf9d.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      client_secret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
      redirect_uri: "http://local.host:9000/api/auth/google"
    });
    var request_length = token_request.length;
    var headers = {
      'Content-length': request_length,
      'Content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    };

    var options = {
      url:'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      body:token_request
    };

    request.post(options,function(error, response, body){
      if(error){
        console.error(error);
      }else{
        //WHAT GOES HERE?

      }
    });
  }
  if(error){
    res.status(403);
  }
}
```

I'm able to exchange the code returned by google for an auth token object successfully and log it to the terminal.  I've been told that I should set a cookie using:

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
res.setCookie('SID','yes',{
  domain:'local.host',
  expires:0,
  path:'/dashboard',
  httpOnly:false
});

 res.status(200);
 res.end();
```

Followed by a controller on the page I'm directing the user to that validates the session.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I didn't see what's you problem is.

Comment: I realized that I need to make the angular controller perform a get request to the server for the initial re-routing of the browser - working on that now. I'll post a code update once I'm done w/ that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already done the hard work so there is no point talking about **[passport.js](http://passportjs.org)** which is actually written to simplify these kind of social login authentication.

So let's come directly to session implementaion logic.

You need to set the following header in your app.js/server.js :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization');
    next();
});
```

Let's say you are returning this token after successful login :

```
{
    name : "some name",
    role : "some role",
    info : "some info"
}
```

You can have a client side function in your angular service or controller :

```
function(user,callback){
    var loginResource = new LoginResource(); //Angular Resource
    loginResource.email = user.email;
    loginResource.password = user.password;
    loginResource.$save(function(result){
        if(typeof result !== 'undefined'){
            if(result.type){
                $localStorage.token = result.token;
                $cookieStore.put('user',result.data);
                $rootScope.currentUser = result.data;
            }
        }
        callback(result);
    }); 
}
```

LoginResource calls your REST endpoint which returns auth token.

You can store your auth token in [localStorage](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage) and [cookieStore](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore).

localStorage makes sure that we are having the token saved even when user has closed the browser session.
If he clears the localStorage and cookieStorage both then log him out as you don't have any valid token to authorize user.

This is the same logic which i am using [here](https://github.com/narendrasoni1989/mean-jwt-auth). If you need more help then let me know.

Comment: I'm struggling with the response object making it back to the browser after google has returned my callback.  Normally, I would just validate the user prior to serving the page, but since I'm using Angular views instead of serving html pages directly from express I'm struggling with it.

Comment: look for ngRoute or ui.router .. both are used for client side routing.

Comment: I'm currently using ui.router for all of my routes in Angular.  Do I need to stand up a route for my callback - since that's where the server response will be sent?

Comment: I was able to get this by changing the response from a res.redirect('/path') to res.writeHead(302,{location:'/path'}) while setting the cookie to manage the session and put in localStorage/cookieStore.

Comment: @JohnEllis that's great buddy, i am very sorry reply too late.I am happy that i was able to help you.